# Postgres sql query to explode all the dates between start and end date for each customer

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with the following columns: `customerID`, `startdate`, `enddate`. E.g.:

```
CustomerID     startdate(mm/dd/yyyy)       Enddate(mm/dd/yyyy)
c1             10-15-2020                  10-18-2020
c2             02-20-2021                  02-25-2021
c3             12-01-2021                  12-08-2021
```

How can I write a SQL query to explode the all the dates between start and end date for each customer respectively?

So expected output would be:

```
CustomerID        exploedcalendardate
c1                10-15-2020
c1                10-16-2020
c1                10-17-2020
c1                10-18-2020
c2                02-20-2021
c2                02-21-2021
c2                02-22-2021
c2                02-23-2021
c2                02-24-2021
c2                02-25-2021
c3                12-01-2021
c3                12-02-2021
c3                12-03-2021
c3                12-04-2021
c3                12-05-2021
c3                12-06-2021
c3                12-07-2021
c3                12-08-2021
```

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? They are two very different products.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to expand each row of a table into a variable number of rows in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64461609/how-to-expand-each-row-of-a-table-into-a-variable-number-of-rows-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using generate_series() function. Here in an example

```
select customerID, dd::date AS exploedcalendardate 
from customer C
JOIN LATERAL generate_series(C.startdate, c.enddate, '1 day'::interval) dd ON true
```

Test the query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d165d/8)